# Check if an array is sorted, return true or false

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, traversal

I am writing an easy program the just returns true if an array is sorted else false and I keep getting an exception in eclipse and I just can't figure out why. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and kind of explain why I'm getting an array out of bounds exception.

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i ++);{
        if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int ar[] = {3,5,6,7};
    System.out.println(isSorted(ar));   
}
```

Comment: Run through your code. You have 4 entries, it should be simple. `i` will equal 3 at some point, what will a[3+1] try to access?

Comment: check your index bounds

Comment: Also note that the code does not do what you say. It will return true if there are two or more consecutive ordered elements, but not necessarily all.

Comment: Tip start your loop at i=1 and compare lower if length >1

Answer (score 37):

Let's look at a cleaner version of the loop you constructed:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++); { 
    if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I should first point out the syntax error in the original loop. Namely, there is a semicolon (`;`) before the curly brace (`{`) that starts the body of the loop. That semicolon should be removed.
Also note that I reformatted the white-space of the code to make it more readable.

Now let's discuss what happens inside your loop. The loop iterator `i` starts at `0` and ends at `a.length - 1`. Since `i` functions as an index of your array, it makes sense pointing out that `a[0]` is the first element and `a[a.length - 1]` the last element of your array. However, in the body of your loop you have written an index of `i + 1` as well. This means that if `i` is equal to `a.length - 1`, your index is equal to `a.length` which is outside of the bounds of the array.

The function `isSorted` also has considerable problems as it returns true the first time `a[i] < a[i+1]` and false the first time it isn't; ergo it does not actually check if the array is sorted at all! Rather, it only checks if the first two entries are sorted.

A function with similar logic but which checks if the array really is sorted is

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) {
// Our strategy will be to compare every element to its successor.
// The array is considered unsorted
// if a successor has a greater value than its predecessor.
// If we reach the end of the loop without finding that the array is unsorted,
// then it must be sorted instead.

// Note that we are always comparing an element to its successor.
// Because of this, we can end the loop after comparing 
// the second-last element to the last one.
// This means the loop iterator will end as an index of the second-last
// element of the array instead of the last one.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
            return false; // It is proven that the array is not sorted.
        }
    }

    return true; // If this part has been reached, the array must be sorted.
}
```

Comment: Worst case complexity is O(n). What is the average time complexity given that data are randomly chosen from a normal distribution? Is it really O(1)? Seems like a bunch of diminishing geometric series whose sum is another geometric series which just gives 4 as n approaches n → ∞ hence O(1). Is this true?

Comment: @nader feels plausible, at each data point the change of early outing is 0.5 so the average time complexity must be much less than O(n)

Comment: (a[i] > a[i + 1] || a[i] == a[i + 1]) would be better

Comment: @E-A really? If 2 items are equal that is fine since a sorted list could indeed have equal values next to each other

Comment: In my case, there were inputs like [1,1,2,3,4,4]

Comment: @E-A And that's a sorted array right. So should return true right?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone using Java 8 and above, here's a simple one-liner:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1).noneMatch(i -> array[i] > array[i + 1]);
}
```

Or a logically-equivalent alternative:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1).allMatch(i -> array[i] <= array[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: first one logic is not right.. new int[]{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1} it fails for the last element.

Comment: @Moshiour Thanks a lot for pointing that out. `anyMatch` should have been `noneMatch`.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 4):

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < a.length - 1 && a[i] < a[i+1]; i++){}
return (i == a.length - 1);
```

- only accesses array elements, last part of end condition are not
  processed if first part ist false
- stops on first not sorted element

Answer (score 3):

With this expression, `a[i+1]`, you are running off the end of the array.

If you must compare to the next element, then stop your iteration 1 element early (and eliminate the semicolon, which Java would interpret as your `for` loop body):

```
// stop one loop early ---v       v--- Remove semicolon here
for(i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i ++){
```

Answer (score 2):

`a[i+1]` when `i == a.length` will give you that error.

For example, in an array of length 10, you have elements 0 to 9.

`a[i+1]` when `i` is 9, will show `a[10]`, which is out of bounds.

To fix:

```
for(i=0; i < a.length-1;i++)
```

Also, your code does not check through the whole array, as soon as return is called, the checking-loop is terminated.
You are simply checking the first value, and only the first value.

AND, you have a semi-colon after your for loop declaration, which is also causing issues

Answer (score 2):

To check whether array is sorted or not we can compare adjacent elements in array.

Check for boundary conditions of `null` & `a.length == 0`

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a){    

    if(a == null) {
        //Depends on what you have to return for null condition
        return false;
    }
    else if(a.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    //If we find any element which is greater then its next element we return false.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }           
    }
    //If array is finished processing then return true as all elements passed the test.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A descending array is also sorted. To account for both ascending and descending arrays, I use the following:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a){
    boolean isSorted = true;
    boolean isAscending = a[1] > a[0];
    if(isAscending) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if(a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }           
        }
    } else {//descending
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if(a[i] < a[i+1]) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }           
        }  
    }    
    return isSorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `a[i+1]` because that value may or may not go off the array.

For example:

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
// A.length is 3.
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) // A goes up to 3, so A[i+1] = A[4]
```

To fix this, simply stop the loop one early.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i ++);{

    if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: an int array cannot be null. Also while your code solves the exception it doesn't actually achieve what the method sets out to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If an array is not in ascending order or descending order then it's not sorted.

I will check whether neighbour elements are sorted or not.
if any element is smaller than its previous element then It's not sorted in ascending order.

```
public static boolean isAscendingOrder(int[] a)
{  
    for ( int i = 0; i < a.length - 1 ; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] > a[i+1] )
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}


// Same with Desending order
public static boolean isDescendingOrder(int[] a)
{  
    for ( int i = 0; i < a.length - 1 ; i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] < a[i+1] )
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static boolean isSorted(int[] a)
{  
   return isAscendingOrder(a) || isDescendingOrder(a);
}
```

This function checks whether the array is in Sorted order or not irrespective of its order i.e, ascending or descending.

Comment: Would you explain your answer please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: The condition ( a[i] > a[i+1] ) is always false in a sorted array. From any sorted array pick any position and swap with any other and the condition will be true exactly where that you put/removed the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean checkElements(int arr[],  int first, int last) {
    while(arr.length > first) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[last-1]) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                return checkElements(arr, first+1, first+2);;
            return false;
        }else {
            if(arr[i] < arr[i+1])
                return checkElements(arr, first+1, first+2);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation about the code, so people don't have to decode it. For example, what is `i`? Where did you declare it? You are validating an ascendent or descendent sort? Try not to answer with just code. Check the [answer] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the array is sorted DESC or ASC:

```
boolean IsSorted(float [] temp)
{
    boolean result=true,result2=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length-1; i++)  
        if (temp[i]< temp[i + 1]) 
                result= false;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length-1; i++)  
        if (temp[i] > temp[i + 1])   
            result2= false;

    return result||result2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkSorted(int a[], int n) {
  for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i-1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: we simple check the neighbour element that is (a[i] > a[i-1] ) and return accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) 
{
    int i,count=0;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++);{
        if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
            count=count+1;
        }  
        }
    if(count==a.length-1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int ar[] = {3,5,6,7};
    System.out.println(isSorted(ar));   
}
```

Here,this is code on checking the array is sorted or not, if it is sorted it return true, else false.I hope you understand the approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the array, the index value is from 0 to n-1(n is the length of the array). When the loop comes at the last index ie n-1 the value of i+1 is n which is outside the array as the array index is only until n-1 so you are getting an array out of bound exception.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test if an array is sorted or not is this way :

```
boolean isSorted (int[] arr) {
        boolean isIt = true;
        int len = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
            len--;
            for (int j = i ; j < len; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j+1]) {isIt = true;}
                else {return false;}
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Because if you use the following code you get true for this array which is not correct

int[] test = {5,6,3,4};

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++); { 
    if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public class checksorted {
    boolean isSorted(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
      return  true;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

The **every()** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
arr.every(function (a, b) {
  return a > b;
});

var arr = [1,2,3] // true

var arr = [3,2,1] // false
```

Comment: noticed this was a question about java, but reviewing the src of .every() will shed some light ;)

Comment: This answer is wrong not only because it's for `js`, but also because it doesn't do what it's supposed to do. `every` function tests only one element at the time, so arg `b` in this case is the index of element `a`. So the provided function only tests if `arr[i] > i`. For `[5, 3, 5]` it returns `true`, while for `[0, 1, 2]` it returns `false`.