# check if first array is sorted and if there are consecutive duplicate elements check second array at the index of duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays

We need to check if the first array is sorted, and if there are consecutive duplicate elements, check the second array at the index of duplicate elements. [This is my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnS7.png)

The output I expect is false since `a[2]=a[3]` and thus we should move to the 2nd array and there `b[2]>b[3]`.

for ex:
1.

```
array1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
array2[]={5,6,4,3,2};
```

this should return **true** because the first array is sorted

2.

```
array1[]={1,2,3,3,4};
array2[]={5,4,3,6,2};
```

this should also return **true** since **`array1[2]=array1[3]`** then we go to the array2 and there
**array2[2]<array2[3]** and hence it should return **true**.

3.

```
array1[]={1,2,3,3,4};
array2[]={5,4,4,4,2};
```

this should also return **true** since **`array1[2]=array1[3]`** then we go to the array2 and there
**array2[2]=array2[3]** and hence it should return **true**.

4.

```
array1[]={1,2,3,3,4};
array2[]={5,6,4,3,2};
```

this should also return **false** since **`array1[2]=array1[3]`** then we go to the array2 and there
**`array2[2]>array2[3]`** and hence it should return **false**.

Comment: case 4) it return true, because in your code you have `if (a [i] < a[i+1]) return true`, and in array1 (1 < 2) so it return true :) ,  you have to change this to solve the problem :).   So please first, check if the array is sorted in separate method, if yes, use a second method to check the same consecutive value and check then the same position in the second array.

Comment: how do i solve this @ibra

Comment: as I said, before : you have to divide your code in two parts.  1) check if the first array is sorted a good explanation is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19458302/3429103 ,  2)  your code to complete the verification of same value successive and check in the second array. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case (4) it return **true**, because in your code you have `if (a [i] < a[i+1]) return true` inside the loop that check the duplicated values. So in array1 (1 < 2) is true, hence it return true.
How to solve this issue, you have to divide your code in two parts.

- 1. check if the first array is sorted a good explanation is in [stackoverflow.com/a/19458302/3429103](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19458302/3429103),
- 2. your code to complete the verification of same value successive and check in the second array.

something like

```
public class Main
{
    public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    
    public static boolean checkDuplicate(int[] a, int b[]) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] == a[i + 1] && b[i] > b[i + 1]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int array1[]={1,2,3,3,4}; 
        int array2[]={5,6,4,3,2};
        
        if(isSorted(array1) && checkDuplicate(array1,array2))
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```